# Making a window open on top of another window in python

Tags: python, focus, python-2.x

I'm using the subprocess library to call a program which would open a new window. The only problem is that this window opens below my terminal, which is a bit of a nuisance.

Is there any way to have the window open above my current window?

Comment: Windows?  Gnome?  KDE?  Mac?  What kind of program do you open -- your own program?  Can that make itself appear on top or must the parent program solve the issue?

Comment: Ah, let me clarify, I'm on Arch linux KDE. It's not my own program unfortunately so I can't control it that way.

Comment: You might be able to tweak KDE to raise that window; if it is a somehow special window (a specific name, a specific executable), then you should be able to configure KDE so that it always keeps exactly *this* window raised above the others.  Might not be exactly what you were searching for but might solve your problem.